# Traveling to Spain

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, us-residents, mexican-citizens

I’m traveling lo Spain using a Mexican passport. I’m a permanent resident of the US holding a green card. My question is do I need a visa to travel to Spain for 10 days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mexico is listed in [Annex II](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32018R1806&from=EN).  Citizens of Mexico **do not** need a visa for short visits to Spain or the rest of the Schengen area.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I was a little confused. You had made it clear. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

According to [Passport index](https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php?p1=mx&fl=&s=yes), Mexican passports have 90 days visa-free to Spain.